# JWT RS256 - Can man in the middle get the token before it reaches the client?

Tags: jwt, rsa

I understand that the client makes a request to the server, server sends back the token which is used by the clients to make requests. I do not understand how this is secure as the man in the middle can catch the response which comes from the server and use that token.
Maybe I do not understand this fully but I would like to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern of a man in the middle somehow getting a copy of the JWT is a valid one, and, if that were to happen, then the MITM could potentially masquerade as a valid user, using his JWT as identification.

*However*, this problem only could easily happen if the data being passed between server and client were completely unencrypted.  Most likely, your app would be using some form of SSL (e.g. HTTPS) for communication between the server and client.  In this case, the most a MITM could obtain would be a bunch of gibberish, which might contain all/part of the JWT.  But, he would not easily be able to back out the original JWT.

The main focus of JWT is that they are tamper proof by the *client*.  This means that a user cannot go into his JWT and change his claims or metadata.  Rather, the server locks away some claims into the JWT, and only the server can control this.  Even a MITM would not be able to tamper with a valid JWT.

Comment: @ClaudiuSocaci An analogy I like to use is that a JWT is like a passport.  If someone steals your passport, then maybe they can pretend to be you, to some extent.  But of course, just having a passport isn't enough to board a plane.  You have to match the photo, be able to answer questions about the information in the passport, etc.  So a JWT is not an all access pass, it just abstracts away having to mess around with passwords during each request.